# Outputting Web Pack as a library

Tags: jquery, webpack

I am in the process of web packing our really old JQuery code to be exposed as a library. I have been successful in getting a minified output but no matter what options I seem to use for the library portion, it doesn't seem to recognize the library at all.

My very basic setup is below, along with an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './public_html/path/to/mchn-old.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'mchn.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'MCHN',
  },
};
```

When I run the CLI to produce the bundle everything finishes without error, but I swap the JS out it's throwing errors that the functions don't exist:

```
TypeError: MCHN.resizeMainElement is not a function
    at (index):126
    at pubads_impl_2020062201.js?21066633:6
    at qg (pubads_impl_2020062201.js?21066633:6)
```

The functions are setup pre ES15 classes and look along the lines of:

```
MCHN.waitForElement = function(selector, callback){
    // console.log($(selector).length);
    if ($(selector).length) {
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            MCHN.waitForElement(selector, callback);
        }, 100);
    }

}
```

How can I change the settings of the webpack config so that I can produce a file that would allow me to call:

```
MCHN.waitForElement('#randomElement');
```

After the files have been webpacked?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ended up building every library target to see if I was simply wrong in my assumption that 'var' was the correct target. That was not the issue, the issue is that I didn't include a module exports object in my jQuery code. When I add:

```
module.exports = {
    waitForElement: MCHN.waitForElement,
}
```

In conjunction with the above configuration, I'm able to call all the existing functions in the library.